# Select query with dynamic column name, target table as well as dynamic where condition in i-batis

Tags: sql, sql-server, mybatis

I want to retrieve records from table 2 using Select query with dynamically returned column name, table name as well as dynamic where condition returned by table 1. I'm using sql server. Here is the following scenario -

```
<typeAlias alias="paramBean" type="com.loyalty.sys.bulkemail.dao.ParamBean" />

<resultMap id="paramBeanMap" class="paramBean">
        <result property="columnName" column="COLUMN_NAME" />
        <result property="tableName" column="TABLE_NAME" />
        <result property="uniqueKey" column="UNIQUE_KEY" />                     
</resultMap>

<select id="getKeywordData" parameterClass="String" resultMap="paramBeanMap">

    SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME, UNIQUE_KEY from LT_TB_SMS_EMAIL_MESSAGE_KEYWORD where KEYWORD
    in #keywordName#

</select>

<select id="selectKeywordValue" parameterClass="paramBean" resultClass="String">

    SELECT #columnName# from #tableName# where #uniqueKey# in #memberNo#

</select>
```

I'm able to get values from first query in ParamBean properties but it is throwing error at column name in second query. I tried to search similar query but unfortunately couldn't found any where. Is it possible in i-batis or i should take another approach to retrieve records with dynamic inputs ? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use direct string replacement, `$param$` for column, table etc. names that are not parameters to your query. This will directly put your `String` in the query. Be careful about SQL injection in this case.

```
<select id="selectKeywordValue" parameterClass="paramBean" resultClass="String">

    SELECT $columnName$ from $tableName$ where $uniqueKey$ in $memberNo$

</select>
```

Note that in this case, your memberNo must be string that looks like `"(val1, val2, val3)"`.

See [3.9.5. Simple Dynamic SQL Elements](https://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch03s09.html) from the document.